# Broken gui/graphics in Code::Blocks

Tags: 16.04, gui, code-blocks

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. Code::Blocks looks like this:

[image] 
Sometimes editor window is visible but tool bars are invisible or unresponsive. How do I fix that ?

Comment: Please check if the necessary libraries are installed according to [this instructions](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Installing_Code::Blocks_nightly_build_on_Ubuntu)